# How do you create a nested array with an append like function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I want holding the data of players which are in an array format. These players are looped over a table in html and are required to be independent from one another.

When I use the push function in JavaScript, it simply unpacks the array and has all the values alongside each other. This is extremely inconvenient for me and I was wondering if there was a push/append function that specifically kept the data in array format.

e.g:

```
output = [];
var one = ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg'];
var two = ['Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg'];
var three = ['Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg'];

output.push([one]);
output.push([two]);
output.push([three]);

Expected Output: [ ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg'], ['Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg'], ['Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg'] ]

Actual Output: ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg', 'Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg', 'Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg']
```

Any other practices that can get me my desired output are massively appreciated.

Comment: `output.push(one, two, three);` would work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push check the api referance :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding square brackets destructures the lists, so you should remove those. You can also push all of the arrays at one time by adding multiple arguments to the push method.

```
output = [];
var one = ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg'];
var two = ['Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg'];
var three = ['Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg'];

output.push(one, two, three);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into it in the morning

Answer (score 1):

The array push method appends a new value at the end of the array

```
    const output = [];
    let one = ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg'];
    let two = ['Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg'];
    let three = ['Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg'];
    
    output.push(one);
    output.push(two);
    output.push(three);
    
    console.log(output);
```

```
Expected Output: [ ['Jim', '12/05/1970', '85kg'], ['Bill', '08/04/1972', '65kg'], ['Anthony', '23/02/1971', '80kg'] ]
```

You can even combine the arrays in one push

```
console.log(output.push(one,two,three))
```

Comment: Strange as when I send the data to a python flask route, it appears as one array. Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it in the morning.